# Find all references to a specific table column in Oracle (10g)

Tags: oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query to search all packages for table and/or column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852993/query-to-search-all-packages-for-table-and-or-column)

I need to be able to locate all references to a specific column within a table in an Oracle 10g instance. I need to find references that may occur in sprocs, packages, triggers and/or views.

This column is being removed and a new one-to-many relationship is taking it's place, I need to verify that I am touching all the points where the single value is being referenced so that I can change it as needed.

*(note: The upgrade to 11g is scheduled, but not imminent)*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4852993/409172

Comment: @jonearles, thanks for the redirect. Just what I needed.

Comment: I don't think user_source has info on views. You'll also have to look at user_views or all_views.