# In Oracle SQL, how do I find where a column may be referenced using just queries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a specific column, called `DELIVER_TO_LOCATION_ID`  , which is in a table called  `apps.po_requisition_lines_all`

I need to dig into the database and derive the continent from the `DELIVER_TO_LOCATION_ID`  ,

In SQL Developer I can't seem to find a way to do this .

any tips appreciated. thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852993/query-to-search-all-packages-for-table-and-or-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143728/how-can-i-find-which-tables-reference-a-given-table-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 1):

You can use following command-

```
desc tableName
```

It'll give you description of table including every column in it having any constraints on it or not like primary key, reference key etc.

Comment: The issue though, is that in SQL Developer you can't see that primary key, reference key info .  thanks