# REGEX help needed in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

How to get all the table names from the below Sql? My sql returns only the last table name.

```
with t as
(select 'select col1,
       (select max(col3) from dd3) max_timestamp
  from dd1,
       dd2
where dd1.col1 = dd2.col1
   and dd1.col1 in(select col1 from dd4)' sql_text from dual)
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(upper(sql_text), '\sFROM\s*(\w|\.|_)*'), '(\w|_|\.)+', 1,2)
  from t
```

Thanks,
DD.

Comment: If you have no dynamic sql in your code, see here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852993/query-to-search-all-packages-for-table-and-or-column

Comment: Thanks Sam. We capture the Sql text from report tool log files and now we need to parse it and extract all the table, view, functions it is using.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more of a regex question than an Oracle question.

If you can run the sql through `REPLACE(REPLACE(sql,CHR(13),' '),CHR(10),NULL)` to replace all newlines with a space, so that the query fits on a single line, here is regex that will return all the tables in group 1 (for the ones after FROM) and group 3 for subsequent items in a list:

```
/FROM ([A-Z0-9$#_]+)(,[\s]*([A-Z0-9$#_]+))*/gi
```

Having multiple groups is not ideal, so I would look at the full match instead, see https://regex101.com/r/OZUalH/1/ for an example (see full match on the right, where every match has from followed by one or more tables).

But let me warn you this is not going to be robust, as these valid FROM clause expressions are not handled:

- "my_table"
- MY_TABLE AS A
- MY_TABLE AS "a"

etc...

**If it were me, I would write a function to run the query through explain plan (execute immediate 'explain plan for ...') and extract the tables from the plan tables (or possibly using SYS.DBMS_XPLAN)**

Comment: Thanks Tony, I have tried parsing and checked plan_table, but the issue is with the views. The plan_table was not showing View name, but the tables of it which we don't want. So trying to write parser.

Comment: Sorry to bother you.. You mean like below. but it is not returning the result.    with t as (select 'select col1, (select max(col3) from dd3) max_timestamp  from dd1, dd2 where dd1.col1 = dd2.col1 and dd1.col1 in(select col1 from dd4)' sql_text from dual)
select regexp_substr(upper(REPLACE(REPLACE(sql_text,CHR(13),' '),CHR(10),NULL)), 'FROM ([A-Z0-9$#_]+)(,[\s]*([A-Z0-9$#_]+))*') from t