# To see whether a column of a table is been used somewhere in the database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

How to check whether a particular column of a table is used in any other object or not in Oracle? For example I have a table **EMPLOYEE** which has a column **BONUS**. I need to check whether this column of this table is been used by any other objects like **View**, **Package** etc in the database.

Comment: Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852993/query-to-search-all-packages-for-table-and-or-column), maybe it is what you want

Comment: Have you tried something? For program unit such as function, proc or package, you can query all_source/dba_source/user_source, but that could be tricky because the programs may not explicitly quote column names. The use of a column in references (foreign key relations) can be checked in all_constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following SQL to check for the table and column used within the object definition

```
SELECT 1
  FROM all_source
 WHERE type IN ('PROCEDURE','PACKAGE BODY','FUNCTION')
   AND text LIKE '%EMPLOYEE%'
   AND text LIKE '%BONUS%';
```

Comment: This method would only identify cases where the table name and column name are on the same line.

Comment: OR can be used instead