# To find out all objects that are using one keyword as a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have data in a config table as below.

## Param_key                                                    param_value

"RAL RREC INCLUDE TERR"                                        "GISS"

"XNA MIF DTT POSTFIX EXCL"                                     "GISS"

"NON CUST DTT POSTFIX INCL"                                    "GISS"

"GIS_TERRITORY_CHNL_XREF"                                      "GISS"

"GIS TERRITORY"                                                "GISS"

Now the last "GIS TERRITORY" is used as a variable as below in a procedure called "Update_xref".

v_gis_territory VARCHAR2(4) := mckb_load.param_tools.get_hash_string('GIS TERRITORY');

Likewise I have to identify all the objects where other values(param_key) of config table are used.

Do we have any table similar to dba_depndencies to achieve above?

Appreciate for any input.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4853032/18747

Comment: Thanks @TonyAndrews . It works.